# Taylor's series of $\sin \frac { 1 }{x }$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to built the Taylor's series of the function $\sin \frac {1}{x}$ in $x=0$ also if $f (x )$ is not defined in this point?

Comment: No, because the function is not analytic at $x=0$. What you can obtain, however, is a Laurent series about $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because $\sin\frac1x$ has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at $\infty$. If you have $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ instead, then yes, since the singularity at $x=0$ is [removable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).

---

Notes.

I see you use the `real-analysis` tag. Note that any real analytic function can be extended as a complex analytic one.

Comment: @mramy thank you for the answer. In the case of $\frac{sin x}{x}$ can I consider $f(x=0)=0$ and the limits of the other derivatives?

Comment: @Anne: In that case, you extend the function as $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x\ne 0$. Then the power series for $f$ is given by the power series for $\sin x$ multiplied by $\frac 1x$.

Comment: yes, but if I consider the first derivative $f'(x)= cos (\frac{1}{x}) \cdot (-\frac{1}{x^2})$ what is the value in this case that I have to use in the taylor's formula?

Comment: @Anne: In the case $f(x)=\sin(\frac1x)$, although $f$ is infinitely differentiable for $x\ne 0$, you *don't* have a Taylor's series at $x=0$ as explained in the answer.// You first derivative is only valide for $x\ne 0$.

Comment: I beg your pardon but I wanted to write the first derivative of $\frac{sin x}{x}$    $$\frac{x \cdot cos x - sin x}{x^2}$$

Comment: @Anne: True for $x\ne0$. What is the question then?

Comment: @Anne: If you are talking about $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $f(0)=1$ case, you first write down the Taylor series for $\sin x$, then divided by $x$; looking at the coefficients you will find the n-th derivative for $f$.

Comment: ok thank you for your help!